# Как вложить json таблицу в один json объект?

Tags: postgresql

Есть функция, которая возвращает таблицу, где одно поле типа `json`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_json_data(limit_in INTEGER, offset_in INTEGER)
    RETURNS TABLE
            (
                data JSON
            )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT data_json.json_data
                     FROM geo.geo_data_json                                 data_json
                              JOIN (SELECT data_json_sub.id
                                        FROM geo.geo_data_json data_json_sub
                                        LIMIT limit_in OFFSET offset_in) AS pagination
                                   ON pagination.id = data_json.id;
END ;
$$;
```

Она возвращает строки такого формата:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "areaSize":8581,
         "height":403,
         "year":2011,
         "code":"01.6294",
      },
      {
         "areaSize":7441,
         "height":530,
         "year":2015,
         "code":"01.6294",
      }
   ]
}
```

^ такой `json` каждую запись.

Мне нужно собрать все результаты запроса в один объект такого формата:

```
{
  "result":[
    {
      "data":[
        {
          "areaSize":8581,
          "height":403,
          "year":2011,
          "code":"01.6294"
        },
        {
          "areaSize":7441,
          "height":530,
          "year":2015,
          "code":"01.6294"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data":[
        {
          "areaSize":8581,
          "height":403,
          "year":2011,
          "code":"01.6294"
        },
        {
          "areaSize":7441,
          "height":530,
          "year":2015,
          "code":"01.6294"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Чтобы в итоге функция возвращала не `RETURNS TABLE (data JSON)`, а `RETURNS JSON`

Пробовал так сделать:

```
SELECT json_build_object('result', select_json_linked_objects(10,0));
```

Но это возвращает те же самые 12 строк, только заворачивает в `result`. И `json_agg` пробовал, но в нем не допускаются множество строк в качестве аргумента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT json_build_object('result', json_agg(row)) from select_json_data(...) as row;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]